# Unexpected keyword 'true' while using `useState` in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-lifecycle-hooks

Here i am trying to set the `open` prop of the  `MUIDrawer` to `true` when the user clicks it but while setting the `state` i am getting an error "Unexpected keyword 'true' "

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Drawer as MUIDrawer,
  ListItem,
  List,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  drawer: {
    width: "190px"
  }
});

const Drawer = props => {
  const { history } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const itemsList = [
    {
      text: "Home",
      icon: <InboxIcon />,
      onClick: () => history.push("/")
    },
    {
      text: "About",
      icon: <MailIcon />,
      onClick: () => history.push("/about")
    },
    {
      text: "Contact",
      icon: <MailIcon />,
      onClick: () => history.push("/contact")
    }
  ];

  

  [state, setState] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleDrawer = {setState(true)}

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            style={{ position: "absolute", right: "0" }}
            onClick={toggleDrawer}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <MUIDrawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        open={state}
      >
        <List>
          {itemsList.map((item, index) => {
            const { text, icon, onClick } = item;
            return (
              <ListItem button key={text} onClick={onClick}>
                {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </MUIDrawer>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Drawer);
```

Comment: `toggleDrawer` should be declared as a **function**.

Comment: You also forgot the ```const``` keyword when you declare your useState hook.
```const [state, setState] = useState(false)```

Comment: thanks, i really for that it's a function

Answer (score 4):

The errors are in:

```
  [state, setState] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleDrawer = {setState(true)}
```

First you forgot the `const` keyword in the useState hook.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
```

And the toggleDrawer must be a function you can do that like the following:

```
const toggleDrawer = () => {setState(true)}
```

or

```
function toggleDrawer(){
   setState(true)
}
```

If you want, you can make the function inside the onClick:

```
<IconButton
   style={{ position: "absolute", right: "0" }}
   onClick={()=>{setState(true)}}
>
```

And finally if you want to make it false when you click it again:

```
<IconButton
   style={{ position: "absolute", right: "0" }}
   onClick={()=>{setState(!state)}}
>
```

In this last case `setState(!state)` will allow you to save the opposite of state.

Then, for each click you make, the state value will change to the opposite of the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `toggleDrawer` as a function, like this:

`const toggleDrawer = () => setState(true)`